# VBA Word Wildcards - finding shortest possible set of characters

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, wildcard

I have trouble finding working solution for couple of hours now. I hope you will help me.

My problem:
I need to find and select in Word a whole sentence after providing the starting and ending strings of particular sentence.
For example, when my starting string is "People" and ending string is "apples." I expect Word to select the whole "People like red apples." sentence in my document. (If such a sentence exists)

For this purpose I prepared a macro which works **almost** like I want. The only problem is that it doesn't select the smallest possible set of characters (which I want it to do). To make it clear let's assume I have this text in my document: `People like smoking. People like red apples.`

Now, when I provide the starting and ending strings to the macro respectively as "People" and "apples.", it selects *all* the text, which contains 2 sentences mentioned above. That is my problem: I wanted it to select **only** the second sentence (`People like red apples.`), not both of them, even though they start with the same word. So, basically, I always want to select the shortest possible set of characters (which in this case is only the last sentence).

Here is a part of my macro in VBA:

```
`text_str = startStr & "*" & endStr

With Application.Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting 
        .Forward = True         
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue  
        .Text = text_str 
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchCase = True       
        .Execute
End With
```

I know the problem is with the Wildcards (or very limited set of regular expressions), so I also tried something like this as the search string:

```
text_str = "(" & startStr & "*){1}" & endStr
```

It also didn't help. I'm stuck here. :/

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What if you use `startStr & "[!?\!.]*" & endStr`? However, `startStr` will match anywhere inside a sentence, not necessarily at the start.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I made mistake while copying your suggestion. There is no error in VBA, but it works exactly the same as with my "solution". :(

Comment: What is the MS Office version?

Comment: I use MS Office 2013. I edited my previous comment, really sorry for confusing you. It "works" but just the same as my ideas (it selects both sentences instead of only the last).

Comment: I would really appreciate any other suggestions to make it finally work as I want. :)

Comment: Ok, I remembered. There is no way to match 0 chars with a wildcard in MS Word. So, you may only use `startStr & "[!?\!.]@" & endStr`. Else, you will need a regular expression.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it works in the example I provided above. But there is another aspect, that I do not always want to search for exactly one sentence by providing start and end, sometimes it is two or more sentences. Just add to my first example this sentence at the end: "I was in the school yesterday.". Now, if I provide "People" and "yesterday." respectively as starting and ending string, nothing is being selected... (and I wanted to find and select two last sentences) :(

Can you help me with it? Even if I'll have to use regular expressions. It is really important for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Selection.Find` has something similar to regular expressions,
but in this case you must use **real** regular expressions.

The pattern (in this particular case) should be:

```
People[^.]+apples\.
```

I wrote an example macro, which:

1. Selects the whole text in the document and assigns it to `src`
   variable (searched by the regex).
2. Sets the cursor at the beginning of the document.
3. Checks whether the pattern can be matched (`regEx.Test`).
4. Executes the regex.
5. Assigns the matched string to `ret` variable.
6. Displays it in a message box.

Below you have a complete macro. Probably you should change it to
select (find) the text matched (instead of the message box).

```
Sub Re()
  Dim startStr As String: startStr = "People"
  Dim endStr As String: endStr = "apples"
  Dim pattern As String: pattern = startStr & "[^.]+" & endStr & "\."
  Dim regEx As New RegExp
  Dim src As String
  Dim ret As String
  Dim colMatches As MatchCollection

  ActiveDocument.Range.Select
  src = ActiveDocument.Range.Text
  Selection.StartOf
  regEx.pattern = pattern
  If (regEx.Test(src)) Then
    Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(src)
    ret = "Match: " & colMatches(0).Value
  Else
    ret = "Matching Failed"
  End If
  MsgBox ret, vbOKOnly, "Result"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! :)
Yes, it works well in the example I provided. But please read my last comment in the previous post. I need it sometimes to select two or more sentences, so in this case I can't exclude the dot character in the pattern. :(
What's more, I do not always want to select exactly one sentence, sometimes I want to select part of the text which starts and ends in a specific way. Consider this example: in Word we have text `apple orange peach grape orange fruit chocolate` and now I want select **only** the part from the second "orange" to the end of "chocolate".

Comment: ... So I want to select _exactly_ `orange fruit chocolate` by providing "orange" as starting string and "chocolate" as ending string. 
As you know, the current pattern will not work as expected, it would select the `orange peach grape orange fruit chocolate` part from the text, so as you can see, it contains extra characters at the beginning which I don't want to be there. Can you help me finding the best pattern to deal with this problem? I have really hard time trying to find working solution.
But anyway, many thanks for your answer! I'll definitely use it, but I need to adjust the pattern